# ffmpeg and hardcoding subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a command like so

```
ffmpeg -i "F:\Filebotted\Rail Wars\Season 1\Rail Wars.S01E07(7).You Look Good in That. 1080p.mkv" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -b:v 750k -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -c:a mp3 -ac 2 -filter_complex "subtitles=F:\Filebotted\Rail Wars\Season 1\Rail Wars.S01E07(7).You Look Good in That. 1080p.mkv,scale=-1:360" "C:\Users\Adin\Desktop\Testy mc test\Rail Wars.S01E07(7).You Look Good in That. 1080p.mkv"
```

Yes it is long but unfortunatly ffmpeg chucks a hissy fit and spits out the following

```
[subtitles @ 00000000050ce7c0] Unable to parse option value "FilebottedRail Wars
Season 1Rail Wars.S01E07(7).You Look Good in That. 1080p.mkv" as image size
    Last message repeated 1 times
[subtitles @ 00000000050ce7c0] Error setting option original_size to value Fileb
ottedRail WarsSeason 1Rail Wars.S01E07(7).You Look Good in That. 1080p.mkv.
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0000000002c714c0] Error applying options to the filter.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002c5c540] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with ar
gs 'F:FilebottedRail WarsSeason 1Rail Wars.S01E07(7).You Look Good in That. 1080
p.mkv'
Error configuring filters.
```

It works just fine when the file is in the same folder as ffmpeg (I found out that it doesn't like ' or - in the filename, but I just spent an hour trying to work out the issue with no avail.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'`, `\` and `:` are among the special escape characters used by FFmpeg.

If you want to include them in a value you need to quote/escape them.

You can try:

```
-filter_complex "subtitles='F\:/Filebotted/Rail Wars/Season 1/Rail Wars.S01E07(7).You Look Good in That. 1080p.mkv',scale=-1:360"
```